# Store characters in C++ tree

Tags: c++, tree, character, binary-tree

How it is possible to store character values in binary tree? I have an CSV file with data, and I have to retrieve that data, search the database, then insert search results. I did that using C++ map from Standard Template Library, but now my task is to do that using tree structure. Searched the web, but haven't found anything about characters, just integers, like this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html

Thanks.

Edin.

Comment: `std::map` actually is a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code from your link and replace `int` by `char`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use "my own" binary tree. 
I would suggest you use, std::map or std::vector (depending on the amount of data, and many other factors) - start with vector, as that's the "easiest" - if that can be proven to be "bad", then change it - if you write your code well, it shouldn't change much.

But more importantly, when you say "character", I suspect you actually mean "string". So a vector with a class or struct containing your elements from the csv file would be a sutiable solution.

Comment: Yes, i mean "string", not just a single character. And I used std::map, but now my boss wants me to do that with tree structure. I wrote a simple C++ program that connects to database, selects table and puts that data in map. Then, reads csv file and store data from it to vectors, and search through map. Finally, inserts results of search into another table. So now, instead of std::map, I have to use binary tree. He suggested me to use vector with 255 elements, each of them representing single character, and node. So I have to store single character in one node, and link it to another node.

Comment: Tell your boss that "map" is a tree structure internally.

Comment: More to the point. tell you boss an `std::map<>` is generally an [RB-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red–black_tree) (at least in every implementation I've ever seen), and is likely to grant near-optimal performance for searches while maintaining log(n) insertion time. If you were building a specialized search tree (radix or some such), I may be inclined to agree with your boss, but if nothing else ask why he/she really wants to pay you to reinvent the already-perfectly-round wheel?